# layout_columnSpan de GridLayout con codigo

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Tengo una app con un GridLayout con varias filas y columnas y quiero que las columnas y filas se combinen entre si (se espandan) dependiendo de una determinada entrada, es decir que este cambio se efectué a través de código :

[image: Quiero que si por ejemplo las filas se combinen como en el recuadro (3)]

Quiero que  las filas se combinen como en el recuadro 3 (por dar un ejemplo ilustrativo)

Se que esto es posible haciéndolo directamente desde el xml pero lo que busco es que mi GridLayout sea dinamica

Answer (score 0):

Hola jeorge solamente tienes que cambiar el setLayoutManager por el siguiente codigo que es :

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager(number, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
```

Con esto se adecuadran los item de tu lista